# How to get img src in JS if its in svg?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating online application and I want to figure out in js what source do I have for image - png or svg.

I'm creating img tag:

```
            var url; //url to icon without extension, like `/img/icon`

            var img = new Image();

            img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            img.onload = function () {

                //Here I want to know if src was png or svg
            };

            img.onerror = function () {


            };

            img.src = url;
```

Server serves svg for the url if svg is available OR png if svg is not available.

I can see in network tab when svg is served, so there should be a way to get this info in js as well. Or at least to understand that image was server in svg format.

[image]

**How do I know in onload event of Image in which format was source received?**

Comment: You can check the `img` var itself in the onload function to see what it has

Comment: https://github.com/andygup/DetectImageType.js/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the src onLoad by reference. Then split the string and look for svg at the end.

```
<img 
  src='www.awesomesite.com/awesomeImage.svg'
  ref={el => this.imageRef = el}
  onLoad={() => console.log(this.imageRef.src) }
/>
```